# Forcing an existing module to be installed in a specific path

Tags: python, module

I have a module already installed in `/usr/lib64/...` by administrator

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 11 2013, 13:13:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print matplotlib.__file__
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc
```

What I want to do now is to have it installed in:

`/home/myname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

But when I tried to install it using this command:

```
$ easy_install-2.7 --install-dir=/home/myname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages matplotlib
```

What I get is this:

```
packages matplotlib 
Searching for matplotlib
Best match: matplotlib 1.3.1
Adding matplotlib 1.3.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for matplotlib
Finished processing dependencies for matplotlib
```

Which means it doesn't get installed at all. I confirmed this with this snippet again:

```
 >>> import matplotlib
 >>> print matplotlib.__file__

 or

 $ ls -lh /home/myname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

How can I get it installed in my desired path and bypassing the already installed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do here (*ideally*) is use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

1. Download [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)
2. Extract `virtualenv-<version>.tar.gz`
3. `cd /path/to/virtualenv`
4. Run: `python virtualenv.py $HOME`

You should then be able tod;

```
pip install matplotlib
```

`which pip` should by something like: `/home/<user>/bin/pip`.

**NB:** You need to also ensure that `$HOME` is in your `$PATH`.

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.11.6.tar.gz#md5=f61cdd983d2c4e6aeabb70b1060d6f49^C
tar zxvf virtualenv-1.11.6.tar.gz ^Cbash-4.2# cd virtualenv-1.11.6^C
python virtualenv.py $HOME^C

which pip  # should be $HOME/bin/pip

pip install matplotlib
```

**Also Note:** Do not cusotmize `PYTHONPATH` in any way. [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) takes care of all the nitty gritty. ALso you may find [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) a useful add-on.

Comment: If I follow these steps, which path will matplotlib be installed?

Comment: To your ``$HOME``. Usually ``$HOME/lib/python2.7/site-packages`` or similar.

Comment: My current python path is this: `export PYTHONPATH=/home/myname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` only. Is this enough? Coz now python cannot recognize the location of matplotlib.

Comment: Remove any ``PYTHONPATH`` settings you may have. virtualenv takes care of all this. The above instructions work and are tested :)

Comment: Thanks a million. I have another problem with calling pylab. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299712/dealing-with-pylab-import-error would you mind?