# Dealing with Pylab import error undefined symbol

Tags: python, module

I have successfully installed and called matplotlib from my home directory here.

```
[myname@sysimm51 ~]$ python 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 11 2013, 13:13:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print matplotlib.__file__
/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc
```

But when I tried to call pylab (needed for my code) it gave me the following ImportError. How can I deal with it?

```
>>> import pylab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 226, in <module>
    import matplotlib.finance
  File "/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/finance.py", line 21, in <module>
    from matplotlib.dates import date2num
  File "/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 130, in <module>
    import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
  File "/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 132, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 35, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: /home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: undefined symbol: _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
```

**Update:**
Using `python --pylab` I get this:

```
$ ipython --pylab
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 11 2013, 13:13:15) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Eventloop or matplotlib integration failed. Is matplotlib installed?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/shellapp.pyc in <lambda>(key)
    221         shell = self.shell
    222         if self.pylab:
--> 223             enable = lambda key: shell.enable_pylab(key, import_all=self.pylab_import_all)
    224             key = self.pylab
    225         elif self.matplotlib:

/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_pylab(self, gui, import_all, welcome_message)
   2917         from IPython.core.pylabtools import import_pylab
   2918 
-> 2919         gui, backend = self.enable_matplotlib(gui)
   2920 
   2921         # We want to prevent the loading of pylab to pollute the user's

/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   2878                 gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(self.pylab_gui_select)
   2879 
-> 2880         pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
   2881         pt.configure_inline_support(self, backend)
   2882 

/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in activate_matplotlib(backend)
    244     matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = backend
    245 
--> 246     import matplotlib.pyplot
    247     matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend(backend)
    248 

/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 import matplotlib
---> 24 import matplotlib.colorbar
     25 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive
     26 from matplotlib.cbook import dedent, silent_list, is_string_like, is_numlike

/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/colorbar.py in <module>()
     25 
     26 import matplotlib as mpl
---> 27 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     28 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     29 import matplotlib.collections as collections

/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/artist.py in <module>()
      6 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
      7 from matplotlib import docstring, rcParams
----> 8 from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
      9                        TransformedPath, Transform
     10 from path import Path

/home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/transforms.py in <module>()
     33 import numpy as np
     34 from numpy import ma
---> 35 from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
     36     update_path_extents)
     37 from numpy.linalg import inv

ImportError: /home/myname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/_path.so: undefined symbol: _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
```

Comment: Looks like you may have some system libraries missing. I can't really tell which though from the output. Perhaps try to search through your package manager for matching files?

Comment: Do you have `IPython`? What happen if you run `IPython --pylab`?